# scala seq.combinations returns out of order results

Tags: scala

scala docs say that combinations method should do the following

```
Iterates over combinations. A _combination_ of length n is a subsequence of the original sequence, with the elements taken in order.
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

but running

```scala
"aba".combinations(3).toList // return List("aab")
```

this is obviously out of order, it is expected to return `List("aba")`. As a side note, this is how it works in other languages, like python `itertools.combinations`, where we get `List("aba")` as expected. Am I misunderstanding how this should work, or is it a bug?

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TdluwxaiQ6CGkckU4Uk3AA

Comment: I guess here `order` means the original sequence order, not the *alphabetic order*.

like `"cba".combinations(2).toList
val res24: List[String] = List(cb, ca, ba)`

But I found this exmaple `"cbc".combinations(2).toList
val res23: List[String] = List(cc, cb)`

Comment: This could be a good discussion topic and possible bug. `combinations` method doesn't handle the order well if the elements have duplicates. It will only preserve the order of its first occurrence